# Creating a class in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm attempting to create a class in Pascal, I am a bit confused about the declaration and syntax. the main thing is an error I'm getting "`Forward declaration not solved Tetromino.Rotate(LongInt)`", I read that I need to declare my procedure in the implementation section but I'm not sure where I'm meant to be putting that. also if you notice anything else wrong with my class declaration please tell me.

```
program Tetris;
{$MODE OBJFPC}
uses crt, sysutils;
type 
    Tetromino = class
    
    private
        TempFace : array [0..15] of char;       
    public
        Face : array[0..15] of char;
        //constructor create();  (idk what this is but read somewhere that you need it)
        procedure Rotate(rotation : integer);
    end;
var
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g : tetromino;
begin
    ReadKey();
end.
```

Comment: `implementation` is the code section of the [`unit`](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Unit) module. In the [`program`](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Program) (main) module procedures/functions/methods implementation can be placed anywhere before the first `begin`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a program module there is no need for division into `interface` and `implementation`. Therefore the error description (to implement the procedure in the `implementation section`) is a little bit misleading. Still, it indicates that the implementation of the `Rotate()` procedure is missing.

So, the error is that you have declared a procedure in the `Tetromino` class, but the implementation of that procedure is missing. You need to implement it somewhere between the class declaration and the `begin .. end` block of the program.

In a `unit` module, which has named sections: `interface` and `implementation`, you declare classes in the `interface` section (if those classes are to be accessible from other modules) and implement them in the `implementation` section.

In the following I outline what you need to do in your program, including the constructor for `Tetromino`

```
program Tetris;
{$MODE OBJFPC}
uses crt, sysutils;
type 
    Tetromino = class
    private
        TempFace : array [0..15] of char;       
    public
        Face : array[0..15] of char;
        constructor create();  (idk what this is but read somewhere that you need it)
        procedure Rotate(rotation : integer);
    end;

var
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g : tetromino;

constructor Tetromino.create;
begin
  // constructor (automatically) aquires a block of memory
  // to hold members of the class
  // to do: initialize member fields of the instance
end;

procedure Tetromino.Rotate(rotation: Integer);
begin
  // implementation of the Rotate() method
end;

begin
    ReadKey();
end.
```

Comment: Wow I'm dumb. I cant believe I didn't catch that, I looked up the error and the guy in question was creating a class in a unit hence why I thought I needed to use implementation, Thanks.

Comment: @ChibiAyano You are welcome. Btw looking at your question history I noted that you have not accepted any of the answers you have got for your questions, although a couple of them deserves to be accepted. You accept an answer by clicking the tick mark beside the best answer so it becomes green. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)